Error de captura
tengo este error
Error in with_random_port():
! Cannot find an available port. Please try again.
Caused by error in startup():
! Failed to start chrome. Error:
Backtrace:

webshot2::webshot(...)
chromote::default_chromote_object()
Chromote$new()
chromote (local) initialize(...)
Chrome$new()
chromote (local) initialize(...)
chromote:::launch_chrome(path, args)
chromote:::with_random_port(launch_chrome_impl, path = path, args = args)
Error en with_random_port(launch_chrome_impl, path = path, args = args):

Caused by error in startup():
! Failed to start chrome. Error:
no se como resolverlo, agradezco la colaboración.
